# BibTeX entry not showing up

Tags: bibtex

I need to insert an European directive in the references of my thesis, but I cannot have it showing up in the bibliography: instead, a black entry comes out.

This is the BibTeX entry:

```
@misc{eu02,
    %author   = "",
    title     = "Directive 2002/91/EC of the European Parliament and of the Council",
    howpublished   = "Official Journal of the European Communities",
    %address  = "",
    year      = "2002",
    month    = "December",
    %note     = "",
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I tried also to use the `booklet` and `proceedings` styles with the same result.

Comment: Which BibTeX style (`.bst` file) are you using?

Comment: @JosephWright: `ieeetr`, to have the entries in the right order. But I have the same problem with `plain` and `alpha`

Comment: You can't use comments inside `.bib` file entries: if I remove the comment lines from your input, I have no issues at all. You probably get a warning about this in the `.blg` file.

Comment: For commenting out fields, the best strategy is to add something to the field name, for instance `Xauthor=` instead of `author=`. BibTeX ignores unknown fields. You may want to use `organization=` in that entry.

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks, it works! I didn't know about comments, and in the wikibook they're used to indicate the optional fields...and I didn't read this: "Be careful if you copy the following templates, the % sign is not valid to comment out lines in bibtex files. If you want to comment out a line, you have to put it outside the entry."

Comment: @JosephWright I hope you won't mind, but it seems bad to leave the question answered in the comments, so I'm auto-answering it. However, if you post your answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joseph pointed out, the error is due to the presence of comments inside the bibliography entry: this is not accepted by BibLaTeX that leaves it empty.

Also the LaTeX Wikibook from which I took the template for the BibTeX entry, states

> Be careful if you copy the following templates, the % sign is not valid to comment out lines in bibtex files. If you want to comment out a line, you have to put it outside the entry.

It also gives a warning in the form (not for the same error):

```
Database file #1: References.bib
You're missing a field name---line 126 of file References.bib
 :     
 :     %month    = "",
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

that explains also the missing line in the document.

A solution is to use non standard names (as egreg said) or by modifying the original name: the field will be ignored by BibTeX.